# IllegalStateExcaption: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android

In my application i want to send an httpRequest on button click.
My button's click event is clickButton. My code is like:

```
public void clickButton(View v){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside Button Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    orderNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.order_no);
    deliverTime=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.delivery_time);
    String id=orderNumber.getText().toString();
    String tim=deliverTime.getText().toString();

    Log.i("Button Click Value", "inside post"+tim);
    String toPass="url?id="+id+"&time="+tim;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("xxxxxxxx", "inside post");
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(toPass);

            Log.i("Http Request", "sending req"+toPass);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Problem in connection", e.toString());
        }

    Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyRestaurantActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but even the first toast is not displaying and the application stops abruptly.
Kindly help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: post the stacktrace looks like `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: I bet its `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because you are doing network stuff in the main UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not perform  the network related operations on MainThread.

Use the `AsyncTask` as below:

```
class CallNetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityname.this);
    progress.setTitle("Sending Mail");
                progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
              progress.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(toPass);

        Log.i("Http Request", "sending req"+toPass);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Problem in connection", e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
             progress.dismiss();
       Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyRestaurantActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Its very helpful. Am very new to android and doing a network operation for the first time. I have modified my code as you said. On button click event coded like:          CallNetworkOperation networkoperation=new CallNetworkOperation();
   networkoperation.execute(null); Whether i need to specify any parameter. Now the execute method shows ambiguity. Kindly help to solve this issue also.

Comment: What kind of ambiguity you are facing ?

Comment: called execute() without null and solved  it. Thank you for your support.